# No Navigation Editor in android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to work on this new navigation editor introduced as a part of architecture components recently.

reference : https://youtu.be/8GCXtCjtg40?t=311

I added the depdencies as mentioned in the documentation
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#navigation

My assumption is that there is a new 'Resource Type' called 'Navigation' introduced. And when I add a 'Navigation' file in my project, android studio will let me view that file in two modes, text and design and I thought that the design mode is the 'Navigation Editor'

I tried what was given in the documentation.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing
Right click the 'res' folder -> new resource file -> resouce type - 'Navigation'.  But, I could not find a resouce type called 'Navigation'

However I was able to create a resource directory of type 'Navigation' and add a xml file in the directory but android studio did not have a design mode for the file.

Why Im I not seeing this 'Navigation' resource type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigator editor tool is only available in Android Studio 3.2 Canary. You can download it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/).

Keep in mind that it's not stable and you can spend many hours resolving weird issues.

Comment: You can refer this official link and generate your project navigation_graph.xml file under res folder. Follow the steps as mentioned in this link below:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 13):

If you use Android Studio 3.2 Beta you can enable Canary feature:

> File → Settings → Experimental → Editor → Enable Navigation Editor

Comment: For OS X this is: Android Studio>Preferences>Experimental>Editor>Enable Navigation Editor

Answer (score 0):

To use the new Architecture Component tools, you need to be running the Android Studio 3.2 Canary build found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/